Output each checksum with its corresponding filename to seperate lines in a text file
I'm trying to output a checksum for six hundred tif files in a directory. I want each line to show the checksum followed by its respective file name.
For example:
b1039a6f0c4295916a82833f507f5e78 vol1_0001.tif
dd3fb454e8d4912934f7626baf105e36 vol1_0002.tif
etc.

Here is what I have tried:
for %%F in (vol1*.*) do certutil -hashfile "%%F" md5 | find /V "hash" >>temp.txt
for %%a in (vol1*.*) do set filename=%%~nxa
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%i in (temp.txt) do set hash=%%i
@echo %hash% %filename% >>CheckSum.md5

The first part works fine, and I get a .txt file of all the checksums I need. But the second part is not working.
All I get is the checksum, and file name pair, for the last file in the directory, repeated a bunch of times.
I have also tried this way on the recommendation of a colleague, but this didn't work either:
@echo off
Set "Folder=C:\Users\Me\desktop\MyFolder"
Set "OutPutFile=%~dp0HashList.md5"
Type nul>"%OutPutFile%"    

SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
@for /f "delims=" %%a in ('Dir /S /B /A-D "%Folder%"') do (
@for /f "skip=1 delims=" %%H in ('CertUtil -hashfile "%%~a" md5 ^| find /V      "hash"') do set "Hash=%%H"
    echo %%a, !Hash: =! 
    echo %%a, !Hash: =! >>"%OutPutFile%"
)

I got a list of the file names, but each had the exact same checksum (for the last file in the directory).

This code solves your problem in the most efficient way:
@echo off
setlocal
set "Folder=C:\Users\Me\desktop\MyFolder"
set "OutPutFile=%~dp0HashList.md5"

(
   for %%F in ("%Folder%\vol1*.*") do (
      set "hash="
      for /F "skip=1" %%a in ('certutil -hashfile "%%F" md5') do (
         if not defined hash (
            echo %%a %%F
            set "hash=1"
         )
      )
   )
) > "%OutPutFile%"

This approach include these efficiency features:

It does not open/seek EOF/write/close the result file to output every checksum line, but keeps it open for all output lines
It does not use an external .exe program (like find.exe) to locate the hash line of every file, but take it directly from the second output line

If the number of files to process is large, like six hundred files, the difference in time from this method to other one that uses find and append >> redirection will be very noticeable...

Thank you, this worked for me perfectly! I see what I was doing now also this one was very fast.

You're very close, but redirecting certutil to find /v "hash" will only return one line, which you then skip with the skip=1. Also, use capital letters for for loop variables, since certain lowercase letters get interpreted as variable modifiers instead.
@echo off
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "Folder=C:\Users\Me\desktop\MyFolder"
set "output_file=%~dp0Hashlist.md5"

for /f "delims=" %%A in ('Dir /S /B /A-D "%Folder%"') do (
    for /f "delims=" %%H in ('CertUtil -hashfile "%%~A" md5 ^| find /V "hash"') do set "Hash=%%H"
    echo !Hash: =! %%A
    >>"%output_file%" echo !Hash: =! %%A
)


I believe you'd find that the modifiers are case-insensitive, too.

I've never tried, but I'm not surprised since command flags are also case-insensitive

@Magoo  Mmmm... I have read this point several times before, but I disagree... The for loop variable is always the last letter and any letter placed before is always a modifier, so there is no chance that a variable be "get interpreted" as a modifier... I used to use different case for modifiers and variables just to easily identify them, but I don't matter if the variable is the same as a modifier and never have had problems...

@SomethingDark : um, from the for /? listing, final paragraph (emphasis mine) In the above examples %I and PATH can be replaced by other valid
values.  The %~ syntax is terminated by a valid FOR variable name.
Picking upper case variable names like %I makes it more readable and
avoids confusion with the modifiers, which are not case sensitive.  - whereas the (meta)variable names ARE case-sensitive.

@Aacini: YMMV. This would occur if you make tyops, like omitting the metavariable name or coding ~nxx instead of ~nx - or vice-versa.

@Aacini I suppose it's about weak meta variables. The code from SomethingDark would fail, if you call it from a loop like FOR /F "tokens=1-2" %%! ("dummy") do call SomethingDark.bat. Because in %%~A" the A would be used as the file-attribute modifier, as it's followed by a valid meta variable character "

@Magoo  Ok. As I see this matter, this is an aid that helps the programmer to avoid errors, but similar aids can be done in many other places and situations. However, sometimes I have read this recomendation in a way that imply that using the letter of a modifier as variable could cause that the variable be interpreted as modifier and, IMHO, such a thing is not possible...
